# Reading from a socket into a buffer

Tags: c++, sockets, memory, buffer

This question might seem simple, but I think it's not so trivial. Or maybe I'm overthinking this, but I'd still like to know.

Let's imagine we have to read data from a TCP socket until we encounter some special character. The data has to be saved somewhere. We don't know the size of the data, so we don't know how large to make our buffer. What are the possible options in this case?

1. **Extend the buffer as more data arrives using `realloc`.** This approach raises a few questions. What are the performance implications of using realloc? It may move memory around, so if there's a lot of data in the buffer (and there can be a lot of data), we'll spend a lot of time moving bytes around.  How much should we extend the buffer size? Do we double it every time? If yes, what about all the wasted space? If we call realloc later with a smaller size, will it truncate the unused bytes?
2. **Allocate new buffers in constant-size chunks and chain them together.** This would work much like the deque container from the C++ standard library, allowing for quickly appending new data. This also has some questions, like how big should we make the block and what to do with the unused space, but at least it has good performance.

What is your opinion on this? Which of these two approaches is better? Maybe there is some other approach I haven't considered?

P.S.:

Personally, I'm leaning more towards the second solution, because I think it can be made pretty fast if we "recycle" the blocks instead of doing dynamic allocations every time a block is needed. The only problem I can see with it is that it hurts locality, but I don't think that it's terribly important for my purposes (processing HTTP-like requests).

Thanks

Comment: Simpiest way is to include request size in the header. That may or may not be possible depending on what protocol you are using.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible

Comment: I personally use std::vector and push back the data until I got it all or until in your case some special character is met. It's what's simplest for me and has served me well so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer the second variant. You may also consider to use just one raw buffer and process the received data before you receive another bunch of data from the socket, i.e. start processing the data before you encounter the special character.

In any case I would not recommend using raw memory and realloc, but use `std::vector` which has its own reallocation, or use `std::array` as a fixed size buffer.

You may also be interested in Boost.Asio's `socket_iostream`s wich provide another abstraction layer above the raw buffer.

Comment: Using `std::vector<>` for network buffers has negative performance implications: it zeroes out the memory which is soon to replaced by data read from the socket.

Answer (score 0):

Method 2 sounds better, however there may be significant ramifications on your parser... i.e. once you find your special marker, dealing with non-contiguous buffers while parsing for HTTP requests may end up being more costly or complex than reallocing a large buffer (method 1).  Net-net: if your parser is trivial, go with 2, if not, go with 1.